# Save state Hide or Show Div for only one div that had the same multiple div

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

I would like to ask question. I had this two div class well which had same html element for each (Actually there is so many well class in my project). Each well div had the functionality to show and hide. My problem is that i want to save the hide/show state for only each well div.Im using jquery and jquery cookie. I managed to get it done but all well div are effected with the jquery cookie. I know its wrong and I doesn't know how to write the jquery cookie properly to save the state for each div only. This is what i come out.

```
<div class="well dark_turq">
    <div class="well-header">
        <h5>Charts and Statistics</h5>
        <ul>
            <li class="collapse_well">
                <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Minimize">
                    <i class="icon-minus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="well-content">
        <div class="tab-content">
            Content 1
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="well green">
    <div class="well-header">
        <h5>Charts and Statistics</h5>
        <ul>
            <li class="collapse_well">
                <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Minimize">
                    <i class="icon-minus"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="well-content">
        <div class="tab-content">
            Content 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And bottom is my jquery code. I already included the jquery cookie.

```
var showing = $.cookie('wellState') == 'show';

if(showing){

    $('.well-content').show();
}
else{
    $('.well-content').hide();
}

$('li.collapse_well a').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).parents('.well').find('.well-content');
    if(container.is(":hidden")) {
      container.slideDown(200);
      $.cookie('wellState', 'show');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
      $(this).attr('title','Minimize');
    } else {
      container.slideUp(200);
      $.cookie('wellState','hide');
      $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
      $(this).attr('title','Maximize');
        }
        return false;
  });
```

I hope somebody can give some help or suggestion for this thread. This is the jsfiddle for that [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4xjsq/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to save state for each div separately, which is logical.
I can suggest you two ways:

1) You assign a unique id to each div.well

```
<div class='well ...' id='wellState_0'>
...
<div class='well ...' id='wellState_1'>
...
```

And then you save those ids in cookies:

`$.cookie($(this).parents('.well').attr('id'), 'show')`

2) You generate ids automatically with javascript via divs' numeration:

```
$.cookie(
    'wellState_' +
    $('.well').index($(this).parents('.well')[0]),
    'show'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback..but again how am i going to call the cookie later after saving it in cookie?..im using the first method..

Comment: Something like this:

`$('body').load(function() {

    $('li.collapse_well a').each(function(){

        var state = $.cookie($(this).parents('.well').attr('id'));

        if (state == 'hide')

            ...

        else

            ...

    })

})`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sayonji for your suggestion..

Important note: I need to give ID to all well classes. Now i manage to do the minimize cookies for each div well class by using each function..inside it i call in the click event function..below is my solution on jquery..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.collapse_well a').each(function(){

        $(this).click(function() {

        var container = $(this).parents('.well').find('.well-content');

        //minimize and maximize well content and declare the cookies inside here
        if(container.is(":hidden")) {
          container.slideDown(200);
          $.cookie($(this).parents('.well').attr('id'), 'show');
          $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-plus').addClass('icon-minus');
          $(this).attr('title','Minimize');
        } else {
          container.slideUp(200);
          $.cookie($(this).parents('.well').attr('id'), 'hide');
          $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
          $(this).attr('title','Maximize');
            }
            return false;

        });
        //show everything when page loaded
        $(this).parents('.well').children('.well-content').show();

       //pass the saved cookies to variable
        var state = $.cookie($(this).parents('.well').attr('id'));

       //show the well content based on cookies condition 
        if(state == 'show' || state == null){
            $(this).parents('.well').children('.well-content').show();
        }
        else{
            $(this).parents('.well').children('.well-content').hide();
             $(this).find('i').removeClass('icon-minus').addClass('icon-plus');
             $(this).attr('title','Maximize');

        }

    });
  });
```